# Page call its masterpage's properties and public methods

Tags: asp.net, oop, object, properties, master-pages

There are some data like title, headers, etc, that are in masterpage. I wanna set these data based on each page that uses masterpage.

For that, I created some properties like `public string title {get; set;}`, and set default values in masterpages's PageLoad().

But, how can I access these properties? As I understand, masterpage is a class that's instantiated for each pageload, so I'd need to find its object to call its properties.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Page.Master` refers to the current page's MasterPage. You can cast this to the relevant type and access the property that way. In the master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" ClassName="MasterExample" %>

<script runat="server">
    public string SiteName
    {
        get { return "My Site Name"; }
    }
</script>
```

Then, in the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MasterExample m = (MasterExample)Page.Master;
  mylabel.Text = m.SiteName;
}
```

See the bottom of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

you should put this code in the design view(in html)

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/NameOfMasterPage.Master" %>
```

under the

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MOCKUPPROJECT._Default" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Now you can change it properties

```
Master.MasterContentHolderPage="some values"
```